# Sync voice with the music through ffmpeg. live karaoke FMS

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, desktop-application, live-streaming, flash-media-server

Using the AMS (FMS) server.

User voice broadcasts to the server.
`ffmpeg` does mix of voice from rtmp and music from disk, and sends to the server

The problem is that the voice or music, do not coincide in time.

Is there a way to sync via `ffmpeg`?

Example

```
-re -i DISK:/path/music.mp3 -i rtmp://x.x.x.x/karaoke/voice -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first,volume=2.000000 -ar 22050 -q:a 2 -ac 2 -f flv rtmp://x.x.x.x/karaoke/stream
```

Time difference between 0.0-0.5 seconds (random)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS` filter to each input audio stream to make sure they both start at 0.

Comment: Thank you. But all my the sounds start at 0 position. The problem of the difference in duration, and now I have it corrected using -ss. Can help timestamps?